# How to query using GremlinPipeline and PipeFunctions in Java?

Tags: date, filter, neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin

In a graph model I have a vertex called `timeCategory` with childs `year-vertices`, `month-vertices` and `day-vertices`. I am able to identify a year with the `edge-label` with `IS_YEAR`, a month with `IS_MONTH`, etc.

I want to do a query that returns all vertices of a given year range similarly to the following code:

```
GremlinPipeline yearPipe = new GremlinPipeline(timeCategory).out("IS_YEAR").property("year")
            .filter(new PipeFunction<Integer, Boolean>() {
                      public Boolean compute(Integer i)
                      {
                        return i < 2013 && i >= 2011;
                      }
                    });
for(Object v : yearPipe) {
  //v is an Integer, but i need the vertex
  System.out.println(v);
}
```

... this works great for printing all property-values (the years as integers), but what I need is a list of all VERTICES which year-properties are between a given range.

My second question is about making a intersection from values in pipes.

For example: I have three pipes, a yearpipe, a monthpipe, and daypipe, and the pipes containg vertices that identifies a year, month, or day.

Is it possible to get all outgoing vertices to one special date...

Semi-Code: allVertices2012-01-01 = yearpipe.out() AND monthpipe.out() AND daypipe.out

sure, i can do some compares in some for-each-loops, but i wanted to know if there is a (simple) gremlin - way to do it better.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions to your problem. Here it is in Gremlin-Groovy:

```
timeCategory.out('IS_YEAR').filter{year = it.getProperty('year'); year < 2013 && year >= 2011}
```

-OR-

```
timeCategory.out('IS_YEAR').property('year').filter{it < 2013 && it >= 2011}.back(1)
```

Here is your answer in Gremlin-Java code (for the second representation above):

```
GremlinPipeline yearPipe = new GremlinPipeline(timeCategory).out("IS_YEAR").property("year")
        .filter(new PipeFunction<Integer, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean compute(Integer i)
            {
                if(i<2013 && i>=2011)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

        }).back(1);
```

Comment: mhh, I still get Integers back from my pipe, but i need the vertex where the Integer is stored. Related to this example it should return be a Iterable<Vertex> year2012Vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some short-tutorials reading, I figuered out that the param on .back(x) should be 2... so, with .back(2) you will get your vertices.
btw. the examples provided at http://markorodriguez.com are much better for a gremlin quick start then these on github-wiki, in my opinion.

To my second question: I found out there is a topic on gremling-users, that describes pretty well my problem:

http://groups.google.com/group/gremlin-users/browse_thread/thread/d245b1a25ac1fac8/514931b1e3bf9e30?lnk=gst&q=intersect#514931b1e3bf9e30